# how to prevent a touch event passed to a UIView's superview?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I've made a program which contains pictures that can be dragged to move on the screen.
also I used UIScrollView since the space is larger than the window.
I subclassed UIView as a pictures view to display the picture and handle touches in this class.
picture views are added as subviews to the scrollView.
but now I have a problem:
when I drag the picture, the scrollView moves together with the picture.
I'm wondering if there is a way to consume the touches in the picture class to prevent them from passing to superview.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should to put your code in "touchesMoved:withEvent:" method of your UIView. If your View will handle this event by yourself, then it should not bubble to superview

Comment: while I do overwrote touchesMoved:withEvent: but the scrollView still scrolls when I drag on its subview who have overwritten touchesMoved:withEvent:

Comment: in fact, it is such a architecture, I use a total view as the subview of scrollview, and then put all the picture views on total view.I do this since I need to scale all picture views at the same time. The total View didn't overwrote touchesMoved:withEvent: (only picture view did),is the where the problem lies?

Comment: You can try to set canCancelContentTouches to NO in your UIScrollView. And set exclusiveTouch to YES in your UIView with image

Comment: @icewind: thanks a lot, my problem is solved by your solution.

Comment: This worked??!  Wow, thank you but I don't quite follow why you set 'you can't cancel touches' on scrollview for it to cancel scroll touches.. seemed a bit counter-intuitive but probably a case of me needing to rtfm.  Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but I had a similar issue and the approved answer (setting `canCancelContentTouches` to `false` in the scroll view and `isExclusiveTouch` to `true` in the subview) did not work for me.

After some experimentation, I found that simply overriding `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_:)` in my subview to return `false` solved the problem:

```
override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Icewind's comment above solved the problem:

You can try to set canCancelContentTouches to NO in your UIScrollView. And set exclusiveTouch to YES in your UIView with image – icewind Mar 7 at 14:22

Answer (score 0):

why you use `UIScrollView`? You have you own scroll picture view so there is no need to use the `UIScrollView` to handle the scroll touch input.

other way around, why you use you own scroll picture view? `UIScrollView` will handle scrolling case so you can just put an `UIImageView` under `UIScrollView` which will work the same unless your own view have some other behaviour but you can subclassing `UIImageView` or `UIView` and no need to scroll the picture by you own because you know `UIScrollView` will do it for you.

Comment: I'm sorry but you misunderstood me. The picture view is not a scroll view, it is an UIView with touch handler. I need drag to change the place of pictures, and since the whole game has a area larger than iPhone's screen, so I need UIScrollView to scale and scroll. Pictures views are subviews of ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

You need subclass `UIScrollView` and override `touchesShouldCancel`:

```
override func touchesShouldCancel(in view: UIView) -> Bool {
    return !(view is MyView) // or whatever your check is
}
```

As a bonus you may want to `scrollView.delaysContentTouches = false` for instant response on your custom controls.