# Prevent UISlider in UIScrollView from triggering scroll

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Using Xcode 9, I have a UISlider as a subview of UIImageView within a horizontal scrolling UIScrollView. My problem is that when the user tries to swipe the slider the scroll action is activated.

Ideally I want the UIImageView and the nested slider not to activate scrolling when touched, only when the user swipes outside should scrolling be allowed. I tried setting the exclusiveTouch property on the slider and UIImageView but it made no difference.

```
   self.slider.exclusiveTouch = YES;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer suggests also setting canCancelContentTouches to NO in your UIScrollView in addition to setting exclusiveTouch on the individual views.

[how to prevent a touch event passed to a UIView's superview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217509/how-to-prevent-a-touch-event-passed-to-a-uiviews-superview#comment5873015_5217638)